# Intent.CreateChooser , it's not working after latest update of android 8

Tags: android, api, xamarin, android-intent

I am working with Xamarin.Android since i update android to use API 27 Intent.CreateChooser  it's not working anymore .Below is sequence of code that I use for Chooser intent it's working fine for api 25 or older but not for api 27, Storage permissions are granted. Thanks for helping.

```
public class OpenFileServiceAndroid : IOpenFileService
{
    public async Task OpenFileService(string fileName)
    {
        string root = null;
        if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
        {
            root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        }

        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(root + "/MyFolder", fileName);

        if (file.Exists())
        {
            Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            string extension = 
                 Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString());

            string mimeType =
                 Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, path);
            intent.SetDataAndType(path, mimeType);

            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
            {   
                Application.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If targetSdkVersion is higher than 24, then [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) is used to grant access.

follow these steps carefully.. [[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt][2] exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](http://[android.os.FileUriExposedException:%20file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt][2]%20exposed%20beyond%20app%20through%20Intent.getData()) This update has been done since nougat..

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks , this worked for me , I added in Application.onCreate() code below {StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());}